# How to measure output impedance of this circuit?

Tags: impedance, measurement

I have the following circuit with an operational frequency range of 100 - 10kHz, always square waves.

[image]

How do I measure the output impedance? I have access to an LCR meter (BK Precision 891.) Do I just attach the meter without the circuit running, or do I need to have the circuit running and have the output active over its operational range?

Comment: The output impedance is affected by the active circuitry so you do have to have the circuit powered up in order to measure it. Under light load and at low frequencies the output impedance of this circuit is essentially zero. At heavy current load and/or extreme voltage swings distortion will creep in, and at high frequencies (which include the sharp edges of your squares) high frequency rolloff will occur but neither of these are due to output impedance per se.

Answer (score 3):

Attach the typical load to the output. Measure the output amplitude.

Now decrease the load impedance by (for example) 10%, and measure again. If you need to be able to drive a wide range of load impedances, use the minimum value for this step.

Then figure out what output impedance explains your results.

If there was no change, then the output impedance is "low enough" and you don't need to worry about it.